# limit of the boundary of a sequence of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $K$ be a compact with empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ ($d\geq2$). For all $n=1,2,...,$ let $F_{n}$ be the points $x\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that the (Euclidian) distance of $x$ to $K$ is $\leq 1/n$. Let $\partial F_{n}$ designate the boundary of $F_{n}$, and $\chi_{n}$ be the characteristic function of $\partial F_{n}$, i.e. $\chi_{n}(x)=1$ if $x\in\partial F_{n}$ and $\chi_{n}(x)=0$ otherwise.

Do we have 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\chi_{n}(x)= \chi_{K}(x)  $$ for all $x$? ($\chi_{K}$ is the characteristic function of $K$)

Comment: What kind of convergence are you looking for?

Comment: Pointwise convergence.

Comment: It cannot converge pointwise, because for $0<\epsilon<1$, the inequality $|\chi_{\partial F_n}(x)-\chi_K(x)|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $\chi_{\partial F_n}(x)=\chi_K(x)$, which is impossible. I think you need a weaker definition of convergence.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I edited and the answer is no.